# Can't send requests to server using Postman anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, postman

I'm using both Ubuntu and Visual Studio Code to launch my server program, they were both sucessfully taking and sending back replies from Postman a few days ago. The server code runs fine, and says the server is up and running at https://loccalhost:8080

But when I try to send a GET request from Postman, I get this error from Postman:

[image: Postman error]

This is the environment I'm using:
[image: environment]

And this is the error I get from my server program when it gets a request:
[image: Server Error]

How ther server is configured:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.set("port", 8080);

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const config = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: "taskfour"
};

const pool = new Pool(config);

//HELLO WORLD
app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: "Hello, World!"});
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Find the server at http://localhost:${app.get("port")}`);

});
```

The server had previously been working fine, Postman was sending requests, doing tests, and my code was passing them. I didn't change much in the meanwhile, I'm not sure what changed. I've tried turning off my proxy server on Postman, but it hasnt' helped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the HTTP listening code is missing, for example:

```
app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port 8080.');
});
```

Comment: I should have included this, but I have these lines later: app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
 console.log(`Find the server at http://localhost:${app.get("port")}`);
  
});

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I didn't realize the postgres service wasn't running. I just needed to enter the command "sudo service postgresql start" in my terminal, and the requests work again.